# Connection reset by peer in MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb

MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytes(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBuffer()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Execute(Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)

Already tried setting connection keep alive

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/VebfUwNFlNk/pQL-QogxdaUJ

Comment: Thanks, we are using Kubernetes. Is there any way to get more information on point # 2? 2. The network connection between the client and the server has been interrupted